# What is a proper way to get the changed values from a table with hundreds of rows (To be sent as form to the backend)?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tables that have hundreds of rows displayed per page, and each row has inputs that can be changed by the user. I want to send only the updated data to the backend so that not too much data will be sent. There is a "save changes" button at the top.

I am not using a form element currently (So to not send the entire table)

What I do is, I give each `<tr>` the row id from the database as a `dataset` attribute, and listen to changes on inputs, then if one of the values of a row is changed, I add this entire row and its inputs to an object that holds all the changed rows. This object is then sent to the backend

```js
let updatedData = {};
let table1Form = document.querySelector('#table_1');
table1Form.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  let row = event.target.closest('tr');
  let rowId = row.dataset.dbRowId;
  let rowInputs = row.querySelectorAll('input');
  updatedData[rowId] = {};
  rowInputs.forEach((input) => {
    if (input.type === "checkbox") {
      updatedData[rowId][input.name] = input.checked;
    } else {
      updatedData[rowId][input.name] = input.value;
    }
  });
});

document.querySelector("#save-changes").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(updatedData);
});
```

```html
<button id="save-changes">Save Changes</button>
<table id="table_1">
  <tr data-db-row-id="1">
    <td><input type="text" name="email" value="foo@example.com" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" value="Foo" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="show" checked="checked" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-db-row-id="2">
    <td><input type="text" name="email" value="bar@example.com" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" value="Bar" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="show" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But it feels cumbersome, and I need to check for each type of input (in the above example I had to have distinction between the `checkbox` and the `text` inputs because they are evaluated differently)

Perhaps there's a better way to do that (with the use of Form Data maybe as well?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not using a form element currently (So to not send the entire table)

Don't know if that is a better way, but in my last project i used something like that, to prevent to submit all data.
In order not to send the entire form, it just needs to stand alone. The assignment to the form is then done via the form attributes.

Based on your example:

```html
<form id="myform" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes">
</form>
<table id="table_1">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[1][email]" value="foo@example.com" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[1][name]" value="Foo" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="data[1][show]" checked="checked" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[2][email]" value="bar@example.com" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[2][name]" value="Bar" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="data[2][show]" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now, you only add the form attribute to the input tags.

```js
document.querySelector('#table_1').addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  let row = event.target.closest('tr');
  let rowInputs = row.querySelectorAll('input');
  rowInputs.forEach((input) => {
    input.setAttribute('form', 'myform');
  });
});
```

Since all browsers except IE understand this, this shouldn't be a problem.
https://caniuse.com/form-attribute

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#form

Comment: That's new to me - you mean I can set a `form` attribute on the inputs with the `id` of the desired form, then submit the form and it will all be "connected" to each other? Do you have link to more information? I didn't find it on MDN

Comment: Update: I found it! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#form. Thank you, I will try it now

Comment: I've found it seconds after you... i've added the reference to my post ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think a possible solution is saving an instance of the table in an object and when the user clicks on the button you iterate through the new table and check whether the values are the same if not send a request to backend.
this way i don't think a checkbox input would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply compare any input element's `value` property with its `defaultValue` property to detect user change. For checkboxes, since their `value` never changes, compare `checked` to `defaultChecked`:

```js
const table1Form = document.querySelector('#table_1');

document.querySelector("#save-changes").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const changedRows = [...table1Form.querySelectorAll('tr[data-db-row-id]')]
    .filter(row => {
      return [...row.querySelectorAll('input')]
        .some(input => {
          switch (input.type) {
            case 'checkbox':
              return input.checked !== input.defaultChecked;
            default:
              return input.value !== input.defaultValue;
          }
        })
      }
  );
  const data = changedRows.map(row => ({ 
      [row.dataset.dbRowId]: 
        [...row.querySelectorAll('input:not([type=checkbox])')].reduce(
          (acc, {name, value}) => ({...acc, [name]: value, foo: 'bar'}), {}
        )
      })
  );
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<button id="save-changes">Save Changes</button>
<table id="table_1">
  <tr data-db-row-id="1">
    <td><input type="text" name="email" value="foo@example.com" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" value="Foo" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="show" checked="checked" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-db-row-id="2">
    <td><input type="text" name="email" value="bar@example.com" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" value="Bar" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="show" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: there is some problem with the result (with key `foo`). But how does defaultValue work if I set the values beforehand? i.e. most of the inputs are already filled with the DB data so it's not the default, how does it work then?

Comment: `defaultValue` is whatever has been provided initially in the HTML as `value="whatever"` when the element first got rendered.